# listView with just images

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-listview, android-image

I am trying to create a listView with just images. Please this is not a stupid question so any help is appreciated. I think my code is correct, but when I run it, it just shows the contentView but empty. It does not show the images I tell it to show.I have created the java file and then two xml files, one with the listView which is the contentView for the java file, and the other for one single row of the listView.

My java file:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Craft extends Activity {
int[]images={R.drawable.one,R.drawable.two,R.drawable.three,R.drawable.four,R.drawable.five,R.drawable.six,R.drawable.seven;

ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.craft);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(Craft.this,images);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context c;
    int[] images;
    int count = 0;

    public MyAdapter(Context c,int imgs[]) {
        super(Craft.this, R.layout.single_row);
        this.c = Craft.this;
        this.images = imgs;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);

        Log.d("Plates", "Count: " + count++);

        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView23);
        myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);

        return row;
    }

}
}
```

my craft.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/woodcrop">
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
```

My single_row.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/woodcrop">
<ImageView
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/one"
    android:id="@+id/imageView23" />
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: your getView() method is not executed in your MyAdapter class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your ListView height to:

```
 <ListView
 .
 .
 .
 android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

I see, you have not overriden getCount() in your adapter:
So your listview dosen't know that there are items.

You should add this to your adapter:

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return images.length;
    }
```

Comment: Can you plz post you complete my craft.xml ?

Comment: thats all of it. it just has the listview

Answer (score -1):

Ty to use this super statement
     Super(c , R.layout.single_row,imgs);